# Start loading after launch - iOS

Tags: ios

When I parse XML in viewDidLoad the data will be parsed while launch screen is shown. But how can I launch app and than let's say blur the view and type Loading. The problem is whenever I put some code in viewDidLoad, it will run while app is launching(launch screen).

Comment: Use `viewDidAppear` to run code after view is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add you code in viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
//Your code here.
    }
```